# ArrayList Size Zero In RecyclerView And No data Displaying

Tags: android, android-studio

I am Trying to get response in recyclerview. I am getting response in log but when i adding it to recyclerView no data is displaying. I am unable to understand what i am missing. This irritate me so much, Please help

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
ArrayList<Model> arrayList;

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item,viewGroup,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Model> arrayList) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    System.out.println("size 111  "+arrayList.size());
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
    Model model = arrayList.get(i);

    myViewHolder.tvName.setText(model.getName());
    myViewHolder.tvEmail.setText(model.getEmail());
    myViewHolder.tvMobile.setText(model.getMobile());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    System.out.println("size "+arrayList.size());
    return arrayList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvName, tvEmail, tvMobile;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvEmail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
        tvMobile = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMobile);
    }
}
```

}

And this is my Activity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
Model model;
ArrayList<Model> arrayList;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
String url = "https://api.androidhive.info/volley/person_array.json";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    getData();



}

protected void getData() {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading......");
    dialog.show();
    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.toString() );
            dialog.hide();
            for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                    String name = object.getString("name");
                    System.out.println("name "+name);
                    String email = object.getString("email");
                    JSONObject object1 = object.getJSONObject("phone");
                    String mobile = object1.getString("mobile");
                    System.out.println("mobile "+mobile);
                    model = new Model(name,email,mobile);
                    arrayList.add(model);
                    System.out.println("activity sizee"+arrayList.size());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Tried everything, but nothing worked please help me out this problem. Where i am making mistake. Please help

Answer (score 4):

You need to notify the changes using [notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) after for loop to tell the adapter to update the listview. The adapter observer will be notified internally that the data source has been changed and it need to go through it and do rebind the data with the layout

```
@Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.toString() );
        dialog.hide();
        for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
            try {
                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                String name = object.getString("name");
                System.out.println("name "+name);
                String email = object.getString("email");
                JSONObject object1 = object.getJSONObject("phone");
                String mobile = object1.getString("mobile");
                System.out.println("mobile "+mobile);
                model = new Model(name,email,mobile);
                arrayList.add(model);
                System.out.println("activity sizee"+arrayList.size());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        }
```